# PixiJS sorting sprites

Tags: javascript, sorting, game-engine, depth-first-search, pixi.js

[image]I was wondering if any body could help me..
Looking for an idea for sorthing child in the stage.
Currently i have the map, mapObjects and the player on the stage working as well.

```
//let say room contain everythings going in the room, background, object, player
  let room = new PIXI.Container();
//start zsorting them
  room.children.sort((a, b) => {
    
     if(a.y < b.y) return -1; //the player will go behind correctly
  };
```

so now the thing is, a got a couple object going infront of other object but the player need to go behind of one and this one gotta stay infront of the other object.
what should i do, if i want them to be sorted correctly

sorry i might be bad for explain.

Comment: ````background.z = 1; rightBigObject.z = 2; player.z = 3; object.z = 4; ```` If that's the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ground` container and add it to the stage first. Make it contain  things that are on the ground (the rabbit will never be visually behind them). Have another container `up` which contains everything that stands up from the ground. Add the up container after you've added the `ground` container.

```js
let room = new PIXI.Container();
let ground = new PIXI.Container();
room.addChild(ground);

// .. add children to ground here

let up = new PIXI.Container();
room.addChild(up);

// add tower, player, bushes to up here.
```

You wont have to sort the children of the stage as their order never changes instead you want to sort the children of the `up` container. Sort it like so:

```js
up.children.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y)
```

Don't sort by `z` but instead sort by `y` as it only matters where they are on the stage vertically. If the rabbit is closer to the top of the screen you want it to be behind things (like the tower) that are closer to the bottom and thereby appear closer to the viewer.

Answer (score -1):

```js
background.z = 1;
tower.z = 2; // big object
player.z = 3;
towerObject.z = 4; // the object which rabbit should be behind

let room = new PIXI.Container();
// supposing sprites above are children of room Container
room.children.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.z < b.z) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.z > b.z) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Comment: If tower.z = 2 and towerObject.z = 4 the object will stay infront of the tower, and it's should be behind him, not working.

Comment: and now, he's not going infront of other trees in the map